# Why is setState re-rendering the component when the value remains the same

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) claims that if you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.

However that doesn't seem to be the case in that example:

```
function Child() {
  useEffect(() => console.log("Re-render Child"));
  return (<div>Child</div>);
}

export default function App() {
  function Counter({ initialCount }) {

    const [state, setState] = useState({value: initialCount });

    useEffect(() => console.log("Re-render"));

    return (
      <>
        Count: {state.value}
        <br />
        <br />
        <button onClick={() => {
          state.value += 1;
          setState(state);
        }}>+1</button>
        <Child></Child>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Counter initialCount={1} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Clicking on the button only changes the inner property `value`, but the object remains the same, so why is React triggering a re-render (including a re-render of children and triggering the `console.log` effect)?

Here is a sandbox to test this: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-hooks-counter-example-wrr2p

Comment: You are using this in the wrong way. Use `useEffect(() => console.log("Re-render"), []);`

Comment: > `Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out.` 
Literally the next line in docs.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Sure, but it also renders children again as well. I've tested it.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman No, I want to trigger the effect on each render, so I shouldn't be providing a `[]` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an old React alpha version `16.7.0-alpha.0` (I don't think the bail out feature was implemented yet ). Just update to the latest version, and the problem is solved : [updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-hooks-counter-example-p3pyd?fontsize=14)

Comment: Good catch! I knew I was missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

use this  code 
at first, you should import the usestate and you should specify where the value will be store in value:state+1

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
`

    setState({value:state+1});
```

Comment: That's not answering the question.